# Insert tabular in footnote in beamer cause blank slides

Tags: tables, beamer, footnotes

In beamer, `tabular` environment in footnote cause unexpected blank slides. (I’d rather have overfull vboxs)

If you add another footnote, the blank slides are gone.

MWE (TeX Live 2022, XeLaTeX):

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  A.\footnote{Tabular here \begin{tabular}{|l|} \hline A \\ \hline B \\ \hline \end{tabular}.}
  
  \pause
  B.% try uncomment the next line
  %\footnote{Footnote.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: blank slides]

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to listen to

> Don't use footnotes in your books, Don.
>
> \author JILL ^{KNUTH} (1962)

---

Dirty hack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  A.\footnote{Tabular here \smash{\begin{tabular}{|l|} \hline A \\ \hline B \\ \hline \end{tabular}}.\vskip1cm}
  
  \pause
  B.% try uncomment the next line
  %\footnote{Footnote.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```